# Does sklearn silhouette_samples depend on the order of the data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I’ve been trying to determine the silhouette scores for each sample in a data set, which contains two different classes. However, the distribution and sample values change depending on how I’ve sorted my data ahead of time. For example, if I sort my dataframe by the class labels (0 & 1) in ascending vs descending order prior to calling silhouette_samples(), the silhouette scores change.

Can someone help me figure out what’s going on? I’d like to know

1. Is there a bug in my code that I’m not aware of?
2. Is this normal behavior of the sklearn silhouette_samples function that I’m
   ignorant of?
3. Or is this a bug in the sklearn silhouette_samples?

The effect occurs with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df_myfeatures #data frame containing features and class labels
'''data frame sorted by output labels in ascending order'''
df1 = df_myfeatures.copy().sort_values(['output_label'], ascending = True) 
'''data frame sorted by output labels in descending order'''
df2 = df_myfeatures.copy().sort_values(['output_label'], ascending = False)

'''
standardize the features ahead of time since they’re on different scales
the X matrix has 26k rows (observations) and 9 columns (features)
'''

standard_scaler = StandardScaler() 
X1 = standard_scaler.fit_transform(df1[cols]) #cols is just a list of columns for fitting
X2 = standard_scaler.fit_transform(df2[cols])
y1 = df1['output_label']
y2 = df2['output_label']

'''find the silhouette scores'''
ss1 = silhouette_samples(X1,y1) 
ss2 = silhouette_samples(X2,y2)

'''plot the distribution'''
plt.hist(ss1, bins =  np.linspace(-1,1,21), alpha = 0.3, label = 'sorted ascending')
plt.hist(ss2, bins =  np.linspace(-1,1,21), alpha = 0.3, label = 'sorted descending')
plt.legend()
plt.title('distribution of silhouette scores')
```

Which generates the following distributions of scores:
[histogram of silhouette scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR0qG.png)

As you can see, the distribution of scores changes depending on the order of data. I’ve verified that there’s not an issue with standard scaler producing different results for the data depending on the order, and that there’s not an issue with the pandas sorting the data and somehow messing up the alignment of different rows across columns. I'm completely stumped, as far as I was aware, there shouldn't be any order effects in the calculation of silhouette scores.

Please, help me understand this behavior! Thanks!

Note: I’m running on a Windows 10 machine, using Anaconda 4.0 (64 bit), Python  v3.5.1, sklearn v0.17.1 and Pandas v0.18.0

Comment: I've just reproduced the same behavior with my own test data and also by removing the `StandardScaler`. I don't know the silhouette plot so I cannot give any clue on the impact of a sort. My advice is to as your question at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) since it seems to be more related to data science than coding.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure with the silhouette score? Did you cluster this data beforehand or something?

Comment: Yes, the data was already clustered. I'm trying to identify observations that have low silhouette scores, and are hence more "confusable".